# debuy orderDTO.getOrderDetailList() is null

Tags: java

In the following code, when I debug `cancel` method, I get error in this line

```
CollectionUtils.isEmpty(orderDTO.getOrderDetailList())
```

While debugging, I see `orderDTO.getOrderDetailList()` returns `null`

This has been perplexing me for a day, I will be grateful for any help

test code

```
@Test
public void cancel() {
    OrderDTO orderDTO = orderService.findOne(ORDER_ID);
    OrderDTO result = orderService.cancel(orderDTO);
    Assert.assertEquals(OrderStatusEnum.CANCEL.getCode(), result.getOrderStatus());
}
```

I am getting error in the `cancel` method

```
   @Override
   @Transactional//事务
   public OrderDTO cancel(OrderDTO orderDTO) {
        OrderMaster orderMaster = new OrderMaster();

        orderDTO.setOrderStatus(OrderStatusEnum.CANCEL.getCode()); //2
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(orderDTO, orderMaster);
        OrderMaster updateResult = orderMasterRepository.save(orderMaster);

        //返回库存   ERROE!!!!  orderDTO.getOrderDetailList() = null
        // ERROE!!!!  orderDTO.getOrderDetailList() = null
        // ERROE!!!!  orderDTO.getOrderDetailList() = null

        if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(orderDTO.getOrderDetailList())) {
            log.error("【取消订单】订单中无商品详情, orderDTO={}", orderDTO);
            throw new SellException(ResultEnum.ORDER_DETAIL_EMPTY);
        }
        List<CartDTO> cartDTOList = 
               orderDTO.getOrderDetailList()
                       .stream()
                       .map(e -> new CartDTO(e.getProductId(), e.getProductQuantity()))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

        productService.increaseStock(cartDTOList);
        //如果支付退款
        if(orderDTO.getOrderStatus().equals(PayStatusEnum.SUCCESS.getCode())){
            //TODO  还没写   Haven't written yet
        }
        return orderDTO;
```

}

my DTO

```
@Data
public class OrderDTO {

    private String orderId; //    订单id
    private String buyerName;   //买家名字
    private String buyerPhone;  //买家手机号
    private String buyerAddress;    //买家地址
    private String buyerOpenid; //买家微信Openid
    private BigDecimal orderAmount; //订单总金额
    private Integer orderStatus; //订单状态, 默认为0新下单
    private Integer payStatus;    //支付状态, 默认为0未支付.
    private Date createTime;    //创建时间
    private Date updateTime;    //更新时间

    List<OrderDetail> orderDetailList;
}
```

I am unable to find the reason why my code is breaking. The `previousfind` method works fine.

Comment: Are you initialising the `orderDetailList` as `orderDetailList = new ArrayList<>` ? Without this, you will get error.

Comment: In the cancel method?       Still error and orderDetailList=null  .         error message         :                                                                                                                                        com.imooc.exception.SellException: 订单详情为空
 at com.imooc.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.cancel(OrderServiceImpl.java:139)
 at com.imooc.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ca742d40.invoke(<generated>)

Comment: try adding this in your `if` condition: `orderDTOP == null || orderDTO.getOrderDetailList() ==null || CollectionUtils.isEmpty(orderDTO.getOrderDetailList())`

Comment: Still error，Can i put the github address?   https://github.com/ztttao/sell/blob/master/src/main/java/com/imooc/service/impl/OrderServiceImpl.java .  cancel method： Line 136. I really bothered you. Thank you.